# Range with increments in Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, for-loop, swiftui, swift5

I would like to iterate a range of Int from 0 to 100 with an increment of a value (i.e 5).
Is there any func or extension that allows me to create this collection and for looping inside a Picker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stride(from: 0, through: 100, by: 5)` as you picker's data source.

With `ForEach`, wrap the result in an array like so:

```
ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 5)), id: \.self) { index in
  ...
}
```

Comment: If I put the stride inside the ForEach, it comes up "Cannot convert value of type 'StrideThrough<Int>' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this context will help resolve your error (same answer as Gereon)?

```
Picker("My Value", selection: $myBinding) {
   ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 5)), id: \.self) { index in
      Text("\(index)")
         .tag(index)
      }
}
```